# How to set gap when solving with cplex

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming

I am writing code in c++ and calling CPLEX to solve it. It finds a very good solution quickly, but takes a very long time trying to improve it. So I want to set the gap to a larger value to terminate the code, and this is what I use:

```
    cplex_model.setParam(EpGap, 0.01);
```

But the compiler gives me an error saying `EpGap` is an undeclared identifier. What is the default name for relative gap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EpGap is a part of an enum within the class IloCplex

```
cplex_model.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap, 0.01);
```

Comment: This removed the error, but the code keeps running even after it is smaller than my gam! I set it cplex_model.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap, 1); but now although the gap is 0.46% it is still running!

Answer (score -1):

`cplex_model.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap, 0.01);` is correct

If the `EpGap` is 1 (1%) it goes to the next feasible solution found that gives a duality gap of 1% or less, so once it goes under 1% it should stop and give you that solution.  So in your case, it may go from duality gap > 1% to 0.43%!